# timestamp as variable in sql query

Tags: python, mysql

I want to use the timestamp-value as a variable for a MySQL-query in python.

```
tsmin = 1527573750;
tsmax = 1527574050;
command = "SELECT * FROM #CMD# WHERE data.#CMD#.TimesTamp BETWEEN 
          FROM_UNIXTIME(tsmin) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(tsmax)";
```

This gives this error: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'tsmin' in 'where clause'")

When I use following command it works fine.

```
command = "SELECT * FROM #CMD# WHERE data.#CMD#.TimesTamp BETWEEN 
          FROM_UNIXTIME(1527573750) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1527574050)"
```

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: If `tsmin` and `tsmax` are variables in the python script, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**f-strings** (Python 3.6+)

```
tsmin = 1527573750;
tsmax = 1527574050;
command = f"SELECT * FROM #CMD# WHERE data.#CMD#.TimesTamp BETWEEN 
          FROM_UNIXTIME({tsmin}) AND FROM_UNIXTIME({tsmax})";
```

**format**

```
tsmin = 1527573750;
tsmax = 1527574050;
command = "SELECT * FROM #CMD# WHERE data.#CMD#.TimesTamp BETWEEN 
          FROM_UNIXTIME({tsmin}) AND FROM_UNIXTIME({tsmax})".format(tsmin=tsmin, tsmax=tsmax);
```

Comment: I've used the format way and it works. Thank you very much!